# Migrate an app from Delphi to Silverlight C#

Tags: delphi, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, migration, delphi-5

I have a legacy desktop accounting application developed using Delphi 5 & Paradox, which I intend to migrate to a web based Silverlight (for the sake of UX) application with SQL Server.

Can anybody suggest a way to implement this quickly?

I know this is a very open-ended question and I am not looking for concrete answers. Instead opinion/experiences from SO users.

My main concern is about migration approach, possible architecture and design patterns (for SL I know of MVVM) implementation.

Comment: I'm also very much interested in this.  I have a legacy winform app that needs migrating and considering Silverlight as well.  Very much concern about being able to migrate quickly.  SO many horror stories with things taking a very long time to do with MVVM.

Comment: @e36M3: I think, you are in a much better situation with a WinForms app as you can probably re-use if not most, at least some parts of your code. But for me it is a total re-write situation :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly?  That's what every manager wants, but I doubt it.

You have fundamentally different models of UIs, and different programming languages.
Unless these applications are small, it is unlikely that will be able to convert them by hand in any short period of time (or even by yourself as it appears the OP implies "I intend").

Gartner Group has analyzed manual migrations, and suggests if everything is "similar" the actual conversion rate is ~~ 150 lines/day, which is possible because you are translating more or less directly from a working, debugged application. (Just how big is the application in SLOC?)  So, if you have 75,000 lines of code, you're looking at 500 man-days minimum. You might make the case that Delphi as programming langauges and C# are similar.  You cannot reasonably make that case for the Delphi UI and Silverlight, so this estimate is a lower bound.

There are those that say, "just throw it away and recode it from scratch".  Unless your productivity exceeds 150 debugged lines of code per day [classic software engineering texts will tell you it is much smaller than this] this will take you even longer.  Usually it fails because you end up forgetting what features exist in the current program, and rediscover them late in development or worse after an attempted reployment.  Usually what happens is the old application continues to evolve while the new one is being built (remember, you're 500 man-days away from the new one minimum!) and the new one has to play catchup with these changes.  If the application has any serious scale (e.g., a million lines) this often prevents the new one from ever being servicable.  Another way to think about this, "how long did it take to build the original application?", and "why should building a replacement be enormously easier?".  YMMV, if you can work miracles.

My very biased opinion (I build langauge translation tools) is that one of the most practical ways to do this is automated translation.  This has its costs, too; they aren't off-the-shelf items no matter what somebody tells you.  You have set up the translator, and that also takes a lot of energy, but that energy is proportional to the size of the *language* and (UI) *library features* used, rather than the application size, so it is far more effective as the program gets large.  This is still on the order of hundreds of man-days to code and test for just for the langauge translation part.    The difference is that once set up, you can apply it to the existing application of whatever size in whatever state it happens to be in.  There's more complications than this, but this approach overcomes the "can't catch up" problem of manual conversions, and the "can't get enough coders to manually translate it".

For more details, see my [answer on how to translate between languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455456/how-to-translate-between-programming-languages/3460977#3460977).

If your application is relatively small, there are IMHO no good answers.  Hand translation or recoding are likely your only (ugly) choices.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create "value add" extras and updates to your application using Silverlight as and when the need for extra functionality comes up until you've got something resembling a full product.

To me developing Silverlight seems to take a very long time and the UX for a business application isn't massively improved over say ASP.NET Ajax (if the Ajax is done properly). I imagine if you were to sit down today and completely re-write a decent size application in Silverlight then Silverlight would be end of life before your development is completed (unless you threw a massive team at it of course)

Answer (score 1):

If your business logic is well separated from the UI, you can start with "porting" your code to Delphi Prism rather than C#. This offers shorter migration path. If your business logic is tightly coupled with UI (as it happened frequently 10-15 years ago), then rewriting everything from scratch could be a better idea.

And once you have all the code in Pascal up and running, rewriting it in C# (if you need it at the end) is almost trivial with help of decompiler.