# Stored Procedure from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Is there any tool to convert Microsoft SQL Server 2008 r2 Stored Procedure to PostgreSQL Function?

**OR**

Need to convert manually by developer?

I came up with pretty [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952922/tool-to-convert-t-sql-sql-server-stored-procedure-to-pgsql-postgre-sql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any tool to convert Microsoft SQL Server 2008 r2 Stored
>   Procedure to PostgreSQL Function?
>   OR
>   Need to convert manually by developer?

To cut long story short, you need a developer to convert them.

If in theory such tool existed, it would be extremely complex (who would need it that badly to pay for it?  The hire a developer to convert them is cheaper). Such application would need to be adjusted (imagine nearly the whole development cycle) for any version changes in both MSSQL and postgres.

If we are talking **data** then it is different story:
For MSSQL server you can check this section - http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_SQL_Server

There is a tool called [fullconvert](https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert) which is able to migrate data