# Bulk translation of C# to Objective C

Tags: c#, objective-c

Our department has inherited two new code bases.  One is in C#, the other is in Objective C.  The first has a bunch of functionality that we need in the second as well.

I realize that there isn't going to be a 1-to-1 relationship that we can run a simple translator to move from C# to Objective C, but is there some tool to do a rough conversion of the syntax.

We're mostly looking for a tool that would do some of the mindless part.  I'm not looking forward to manually translating 1000 function headers, for example, when the format for both is so well defined.

**EDIT**

Even something we could run on an individual methods one at a time would speed up the process significantly.

Comment: I personally have no idea - but good luck with it :)

Comment: Personally I would write a bunch of Python scripts. Ruby would also be a good choice.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455456/how-to-translate-between-programming-languages/3460977#3460977  There is a C# front end already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting rid of the C# code base? If not then it seems like you can look at this from a different angle - rather than undertaking the huge effort of converting thousands of classes that rely on probably scores of API's, how about exposing your existing functionality as services that can be called from your Objective-C code? You can do this using web services.

Alternatively you can take a look at Mono/Cocoa#, though I doubt this is going to be a viable solution for your problem.