# Convert VB6 app to WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb6, vb6-migration

Is it possible to convert a VB6 app to WPF using automated tools?

I'm aware of tools to convert to Winforms, but what about WPF?

Is there a pathway from Winforms to WPF that could be utilised?

Comment: Even if you *could* it doesn't mean you *should* - it is probably better to re-write it if this is what you want as the two are completely different technologies

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455456/how-to-translate-between-programming-languages/3460977#3460977

Comment: @Matt "It is probably better to rewrite". It depends how expensive the rewrite would be. Some organisations have millions of lines of VB6. It might be a bad deal for them to invest a number of person-years completely rewriting a working application, in order to gain a productivity benefit when maintaining it later.

Comment: @Markj - I agree - my point was that VB->WPF is not the best upgrade path so if you must have WPF you would be better to re-write or else upgrade to .NET Winforms

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it but I googled it for you. Try this tool by [Davide Senatore](http://66.163.168.225/babelfish/translate_url_content?lp=it_en&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.ugidotnet.org%2Fdsenatore%2Farchive%2F2006%2F11%2F26%2F57347.aspx&.intl=us). The link is his page in babel fish because the original is in Italian. If you try it post some feedback for others.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you probably find tool to convert the plain form layout, you have to rewrite the logic behind, since the approach is definitely different. If you don't keep this in mind ( so you replicate the same as the VB6 app ewxactly in the WPF one ) you will probably create some sort of unmaintainable blob.