# Convert a Visual Basic 6 Project to Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, vb6

I´m trying to convert an old VB6 project to Qt/C++. Anyone knows a throughout way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Start from scratch. Unfortunately, whatever solution you do come up with; I have a feeling it will be pretty close to that.

Comment: Rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: With a different language, different compiler, and different platform one would expect a different design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all very nice for others to tell you to rewrite your application from scratch.  They don't have to do the work.

It is possible to translate automatically from one language to another, in spite of serious differences in "style".   You might not get the nicest program in the world, but then, with all these great coders that were around when it was built, you already don't have the nicest application in the world.   And if you follow the advice of those that say, "rebuild it from scratch", unless it is tiny, you likely won't have any program at all.

See my [SO answer on how to translate programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460977/120163) for an alternative. Also not easy or cheap, but practical.

Answer (score 1):

Qt and VB have entirely different idioms, I don't think it would make sense to "port" the application.  I hope there is no tool to convert between those two platforms anyway, god help the author(s) if there was.

Your best bet is to start writing the application from scratch in Qt, it's not a VB6 application anymore.

Having the old application as a *requirements* reference is fairly magnificent.  It will describe your inputs, outputs fairly well.  You should avoid using it as a *design* reference, though.  I mean that from the programming point of view.  The GUI elements can look the same if its appropriate, though it is a good opportunity to reconsider if there is a better way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Though i am very late but for reference I think I should write an answer.
I understand that I am not talking about **Translation** of VB to QT, But Feasibility of compilation using QT library.
The tool **[Gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html)** will be helpfull.
It takes a similar almost VB like syntax and use QT and GTK to render widgets.
If you need C++ code then NO it cant do.

EDIT: Gambas3 is a VB like RAD environment. It Uses QT to render widgets. The syntax is almost similar to VB. With few modifications existing apps can be used.
This way rewrite of application may be avoided.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).