# Antlr - Convert C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, antlr, antlr4

Is there anyway to use Antlr for Converting C# to Java, I tried to look out for any article or sample, but couldn't find anything.

So the questions is ..... 
Can I do this using Antlr ?
Any starting points\tips on how to start on it is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANTLR from Java to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069592/antlr-from-java-to-c-sharp) This post includes the opposite C# to Java as well.

Comment: A starting point would be the C# grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp . Then you can use the listener to walk the AST and generate Java code.

Comment: @vyrp it's better to use Visitor with result value (string) instead of listener.