# Right tool for translating a DSL into SQL?

Tags: sql, parsing, code-generation, dsl, lexer

I have a domain specific language that can be translated to SQL. Must I write my own lexer, parser, and code generator, or are there tools that could help me?

Comment: Do you plan to parse your domain specific language syntax in SQL, too?

Comment: Let me rephrase: What is the host language that would do the SQL generation?

Comment: It really depends on the language you're using & how complex your DSL is.

Answer (score 2):

If your DSL is designed for readability by the DSL coder, then yes, you need a lexer, a parser and a code generator.

(Other answers suggest that if you code the DSL "in the syntax of your 'meta language'" you don't need these mechansims; while that may be true, it optimizes for embeddability of the DSL in the meta-language rather than its readability for end users, which I think is a poor tradeoff).

No, you don't have to write them from scratch.

There are lots of parser-generators in the wild (YACC, Bison, ANTLR, JavaCC) which will help you focus on coding just grammar rules for your DSL; they provide lots of low-level parsing machinery to process/execute your grammar rules as a parsing engine.  Still, you have to spend effort bending your conceptual grammar to limitations of the particular parser generator (LALR(1), LL(k), ...)   ANTLR/Bison/Yacc will help you build trees; you have to do explicit work to do this.  After that, you are on your own with traditional parsers.  Most people end up being kind of surprised once they get there (if they get this far; parsers for real languages tend to be more work than they expect.

That's because there is a lot of [Life After Parsing](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html): symbol tables, code analysis, code generation.    Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is designed to help you build parsing rules with minimal constraints from the grammar engine; automatically builds trees (look, ma, no hands!) and provides a lot of support for code transformation in a wide variety of ways.  In addition, DMS provides a perspective and tooling to support conversion between DSL ("your language") fragments and the target in structured ways using the source/target patterns pairs to specify the mapping.  For OP's specific purpose, DMS can be obtained with a SQL2011 grammar, providing a nice baseline for writing the target patterns.

To read more about automated conversion with tools, see my [SO discussion on translating between languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460977/120163).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read this book: [Language Implementation Patterns](http://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) by Terence Parr from The Pragmatic Programmers series. Its a thorough introduction to parsing, translating and compiling. It relies heavily on [ANTLR by Terence Parr](http://www.antlr.org/) for examples, but is general enough to get you going in other languages and systems.

Answer (score 1):

This depends heavily on the language you will use, but Groovy, Ruby, Scala, F# and Haskell are good languages for doing this.

Which language you use will impact which tools you should also use.

You can do this in C, for example, but it would be more work, and may not look as nice for the user.

Some languages you will need to use tools to help with the parser, others are better without the tools.

You may want to read through this book to learn much more on the subject of DSLs, *DSLs in Action*.

http://manning.com/ghosh/

Answer (score 1):

I have a similiar project to yours. I think you should check out Xtext and Xtend, since they can be used directly in Eclipse, you can easily get intellisense, grammer, lexer. I tried to produce SQL code and it has been a succesful project till now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like Eli, which is intended to accept a specification and generate a translator from it:

http://eli-project.sourceforge.net/

On the other hand, you might be just as happy writing your parser with a nice generation tool like ANTLR and coding the AST and code generator yourself.

Code generation that writes a high-level language like SQL probably isn't very hard to implement, assuming the translation from your DSL is straightforward.

If it were me, I'd write the thing in OCaml using ocamllex and ocamlyacc, but for that you first need to know OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a lexer, a parser and a code generator if you're using a proper meta-language (e.g., Lisp). Everything is already included - you can build your DSL on top of S-expressions, you can generate a host part of your code in Lisp itself.

Even if you want a special syntax for your DSL, it is very easy to embed a parser into a meta-language.