# Creating C code from Java

Tags: java, c, code-generation, libraries

I want to create some simple C code from Java, and I was wondering if there are some libraries that could help me. Sadly my google skills are not too good and my results are way off. ("C libraries for Java", "creating c code in java", etc).

My idea would be something like create C file and use method 
`createMethod(name, argument, return, code)` instead of having to just create a document and write strings like

```
return name(argument) {
   code
}
```

Nevertheless, I am little pessimistic and I think that most probably I will just have to create the C code by creating a document, and writing into it the c lines.

Comment: What advantage do you see in this approach that the code written in C doesn't give to you?

Comment: The advantage is that the C code is simple, but the way its generated is non-trivial, dynamic and automatic; therefore, I use Java in which I have more experience. If I used C, I would still like some kind of library help. @BalusC not sure if I expressed it right, the main project is Java and I need to create a few 100-200 lines of C code (in 2+ files)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455456/how-to-translate-between-programming-languages/3460977#3460977

Comment: Interesting reading, and I do agree on the complexity of automatic code translation. I just figure maybe someone had written a library to write  simple C files. So far I have not been able to find any, and inputting to a text files seems to be the nasty but easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One can use [JCodeModel](http://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JCodeModel.html) to create (Java) source code. You could create your own C targeted API mimicking the JCodeModel API. Maybe even extend the JCodeModel classes.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will take a look. Seems like if I don't get an  already done library, then maybe I could use this to create a C-library/API. I hope it wont be too hard to do.