# automatic pseudo code to c language converter

Tags: parsing, semantics, pseudocode, intermediate-code

I'm trying to write a translator for pseudo-code to c language.which phases of compiler are necessary?
I tried lexical,syntax,semantic,intermediate code is enough or machine code is necessary.
I tried flex,bison for the above phases. Is it correct?

Comment: Once you've defined "pseudo" code enough to be able to construct a compiler for it, you no longer deal with pseudo code, you deal with just another programming language. So your question is basically "how do I write a compiler" which has already been asked a hundred times.

Comment: not like that.my input is pseudo code (algorithm) and I want to convert it to c language and my output is c language corresponding to that pseudo code

Comment: @TintuJames: You didn't understand what delnan told you.  Until you understand that, you won't make any real progress.  And yes, you will likely need all the mechanisms you've described.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455456/what-kinds-of-patterns-could-i-enforce-on-the-code-to-make-it-easier-to-translat/3460977#3460977

Answer (score 0):

Yea, following the replies on your question; you want to basically design a compiler for a 'new' language.

The new language will have it's own syntax (the algorithm you mentioned) so you'll just need to design a compiler with that configuration, take in *algorithim* and output valid *C code*

Comment: my doubt is how can i convert c language from machine language and is there any automated tool

Comment: There are no "automated tools" that can take in your imagined language and magically generate C.   The best you can hope for is that you can *define* that language using some formal notation and hand it to an engine that can convert such a definition into a compiler.  People have built research tools as PhD theses to try to do this.  None of them are practical at this point.  It is still necessary to build a fair amount of machinery on a per-language basis to "replace" what we don't know how to specify/implement as an automatic compiler generator.  *You need to go read a good compiler book.*

Comment: @TinuJames: ...wait... you said "psuedocode" in your question, and now you say "from machine language".  Machine language isn't psuedo code; it *is* a formal langauge for each machine.  None of what has been otherwise said changes.  But it is clear that you are not being clear about your actual problem.

Comment: I agree with Ira, what are you trying to do?