# Reverse engineering DataStage code into Pig (for Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, reverse-engineering, etl, datastage

I have a landscape of datastage applications which I want to reverse engineer into Pig... Rather than having to write fresh Pig code and try to replicate the datastage functionality.

Has anyone had experience of doing something similar?

Any tips on the best approach would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a code migration from DataStage to Pig.

This can be done with a [program transformation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), which are designed to parse/analyze/transform complex software systems.

You can learn more about the issues of using such a tool
at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460977/120163